# How to check if a file is corrupt?

Tags: vba

I have a loop that opens word documents however there are a few that are corrupted, I can't open them manually either,

The code I'm using to open is,

```
Set newdoc = objWord.Documents.Open(saveFolder & Filename)
```

This fails with the error

> "Run-time error 5792, the file appears to be corrupted".

Is it possible to tell that the file is corrupt before trying to open it?

Comment: Use an [`On Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement) error handler and see if `err.number = 5792` ?

Comment: The only way for any program to know if some file is corrupt is to try to process it. So you have to open it to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can test it while trying to open it.

```
On Error Resume Next ' deactivate error reporting
Set newdoc = Nothing
Set newdoc = objWord.Documents.Open(saveFolder & Filename)

' check if trying to open it produced an error
If Err.Number = 5792 Then
    Msgbox "'" & saveFolder & Filename & "' is corrupt."
    Err.Clear
End If

On Error Goto 0  ' re-activate error reporting. Do not forget this!

' if an error occured during opening then newdoc is nothing
If Not newdoc Is Nothing

    ' do what you want to do with the opened file

Else

    ' do what you want to do with a corrupt file

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

your best bet here is to use error handling.

Something like

```
On Error GoTo skip
Set newdoc = objWord.Documents.Open(saveFolder & Filename)
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function
skip:
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBA it is best to keep errors to well defined functions (TryFunctions) that deal with one action and return true(no error)  or false(there was an error), and use a byref parameter to return the actual result.

```
Public Function TryOpenDoc(byVal ipPath as string, ByRef ipDoc as Word.Document) as Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    set ipDoc = Application.Documents.Open(ipPath)
    TryOpenDoc = Err.Number = 0
    Err.Clear

End Function
```

This function could be then used as follows

```
If TryOpenDoc(saveFolder & Filename, newdoc) then
   
    <Code to process opened document>

Else

    ' raise an error, do a MsgBox or debug.print a message
    Debug.print "Could not open " & saveFolder & Filename"

End If
```

Although it is more common to use  'If Not Try....' so that you can deal with the error before continuing on the happy code path.